# How to disable eqeqeq for create-react-app --typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have tried several things, but I can't find way how to disable eqeqeq for my project.

My project is created via create-react-app --typescript

Here are screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okTMm.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifSWH.jpg

I have tried several plugins for eslint or tslint

I have tried several config files:

```
.eslintrc
.eslint.config
.eslint.json
.tslintrc
.tslint.config
.tslint.json
```

or even in package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
  "rules": {
    "eqeqeq": "off"
  }
},
```

Rules in files rc, .json or .config I have tried with several combinations

```
{
  "rules": {
    "eqeqeq": "off" // never, 0, 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Try setting it to `"eqeqeq": 0`

Comment: doesn't help, try create-react-app test --typescript and then yarn start

Answer (score 3):

Create-react-app disables external eslint config by default.
To extend default eslint config, set a environment variable like this.

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

And then you can use any of the eslint config setting like `package.json`or `.eslintrc.js` etc.

For more information https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config

This is experimental feature as of react-scripts 3.3.0 but it at least it should work with this.